# Field content visible in a View not appearing in SSRS Dataset

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I've created a number of calculated columns in a SQL Server 2008 R2 table and want to have the details displayed in a SSRS report.

The **view** I'm using to show the columns is:

```
SELECT 
       sys.tables.name                 AS TableName, 
       sys.computed_columns.name       AS FieldName, 
       sys.types.name                  AS FieldType, 
       sys.computed_columns.max_length AS Size, 
       sys.computed_columns.definition AS Calculation 
FROM   
       sys.computed_columns 
       INNER JOIN sys.tables 
               ON sys.tables.object_id = sys.computed_columns.object_id 
       INNER JOIN sys.types 
               ON sys.computed_columns.system_type_id = sys.types.system_type_id
```

and in Management Studio this returns the expected results

```
TableName     Field Name                       Type Size  Calculation                      
LB_LANDBKG    Calc_Year_leg_departure_date     int  4     (datepart(year,[TOUR_DATE]))  
LB_LANDBKG    Calc_Month_leg_departure_date    int  4     (datepart(month,[TOUR_DATE]))
LB_LANDBKG    Calc_Quarter_leg_departure_date  int  4     (datepart(quarter,[TOUR_DATE]))
```

However when I try to use this View in a SSRS DataSet I get all the columns but the calculation column is blank.

```
TableName   Field Name                      Type    Size    Calculation                      
LB_LANDBKG  Calc_Year_leg_departure_date    int     4       
LB_LANDBKG  Calc_Month_leg_departure_date   int     4   
LB_LANDBKG  Calc_Quarter_leg_departure_date int     4
```

I've tried TRIMing this but still nothing. Any ideas why this doesn't appear?

Comment: Have you created an actual View object for this query, or have you used the query directly in the dataset definition? I just replicated this report in 2008 R2 and the Calculation column displayed without any problems, so the only thing I can think of is some kind of security issue preventing that column displaying. What kind of credentials are you using in the report data source?

Comment: Hi Nathan Thanks for the quick reply, it's a View i'm using; the credentials are a local readonly SQL Account we use for all our reporting. I'll try with an account with more access and post it here. Jim

Comment: Hi Nathan, You were right, when I connect the dataset using Admin credentials I can see all of the columns. Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: @jim Good to hear you've solved your issue. Could you please provide an answer to your own question with some details? This will make it easier for others with the same problem to spot the solution.